# Interpolation in strings made using backtick operator

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I'm learning Angular 2 and I came across a few new things. I used ScratchJS extension of Chrome browser to learn TypeScript. While doing that, this is what I did for a backtick (`) string:

```
let user='user';
let msg=`Welcome ${user}! 
I can write multi-line string.

This is awesome!
`;
console.log(msg);
```

As you can see, this is how the variable user is used in the string. But when I do the same thing in an Angular 2 project, it's a bit different (and doing things like above will throw an error). For my dummy Angular 2 project, I made a simple component:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `

      Hi,  {{user}}

      I can write multi-line string.

      This is awesome!
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class UserComponent {

  user:string='John Doe';
  constructor() { 
  }
}
```

This works. But here, I'm using string interpolation using:

```
{{}}
```

instead of:

```
${}
```

And if I use that, it will throw an error. I know I understood some facts wrong. But can anyone explain what is it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`{{ foo }}` will be handled by the template engine of `Angular`, binding the foo property defined in your class.

`${ bar }` will be handled by the `Javascript string interpolation`, which, while rendering, have no clue of what is the property `bar` of your object.

This is something closely related to how `Angular` work, this is not related to `typescript` or anything else. You can still use `${}` if you are not in your `Angular` project, or not in the template.

For example, something like this should work, since the expression is evaluated before being returned, and is not dependant of the template engine:

```
public getUsername(): string {
    let username = 'test';
    return `Hi ${username}`;
}
```

Comment: Is it also Possible to use a Pipe here ?
I want to some Strings for Translation in variables which are later displayed in a mat component

Answer (score 2):

`${}` it is a string interpolation to display a value of string between typescript code.
And `{{}}` is interpolation to display the content in HTML template.